# Laravel Querying Relation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have two models: `User` & `Tag`. They have a many-to-many relation.

```
Table users   : id, email, password...
Table tags    : id, name...
table tag_user: id, tag_id, user_id
```

If can use this code to get an array with all `Tag`s a `User` has:

```php
$tagArray = User::find($user_id)->tags;
```

However, I can't find a quicker way to get a simple array with all the tags ids. Something like this:

```php
$tagIdArray = array(1, 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the `lists` method, on the `tags` **method**.

```
$tagIdArray = User::find($userId)->tags->lists('id');
```

Comment: tags not tags()
$tagIdArray = User::find($userId)->tags->lists('id');